# fastest way to match two nodes attribute in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have two groups of nodes in neo4j. The `Mail` node have this form

```
{
    time : year/month/day,
    content : Hey Anna Sorry I took awhile getting ...
}
```

The node `word` have this form:

```
{
  word : ***
}
```

I want to match all the node `word` with the node `Mail` which contains that words in their content in a specific range of time. So I write this query:

```
MATCH (n:Mail) 
WHERE 
  n.time>'2001/01/01' and n.time<'2001/02/01'
MATCH (w:Word) 
WHERE 
  ANY(word IN split(n.content,' ') WHERE word = w.word)
return n.content as content, w.word as word
```

But it take a lot of time for execution. I think `Mail.content` has too many words to run this query and there are too many `Mail` and `Word` to analyse. They are respectively 1642 and 12379.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The heaviest operation will be in the join between `n` and `w`, which will be a cartesian product. You will not find a way around this unless you change your data model.

However, you could likely improve performance by using the `CONTAINS` operator, instead of `any()`:

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (n:Mail) 
WHERE 
  n.time>'2001/01/01' and n.time<'2001/02/01'
MATCH (w:Word) 
WHERE n.content CONTAINS w.word
return n.content as content, w.word as word
```